# Trouble starting Apache24

Tags: apache, port80

I was following along with a tutorial on Youtube and everything was going well until I started the service for Apache24. I realized that something was running on port 80. I looked in my command prompt and I realized that there are two things that were with port 80. The first one was Apache24 which is listening to port 80 and the other is chrome which is established on port 80. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try finding out which service hogs port 80 and stop that service. Or, kill the offending process.

`netstat -tulpen` will show you which process (it's process ID is listed as `PID` on the very right of the output) uses port `80` (listed underneath `Local Address`, look for the `:80` part). Note the PID.

Do a `kill {PID}`, so if the PID is, for example, `123`, do `kill 123`. If that does not work, try to be be more ride and issue a `kill -9 {PID}`.